# jQuery: first-child (without id or classes)

Tags: javascript, jquery

That's is the html structure:  (see also in jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/hQ5dZ/)

```
<div id="fields">    
    <div>
        <input type="file" />
        <input type="button" value="+add">
    <div>
    <div> 
        <input type="file" />
        <input type="button" value="+add">
    <div>
</div>
```

The second jQuery-statement below does not work, why?

```
$('#fields').children().hide();
$('#fields :first-child').show();
```

EDIT: Desired Behaviour -> First div-child (with its content) should appear

Comment: its working for me in chrome

Comment: What is the behaviour you were hoping for?

Comment: the first div-child should appear

Comment: I have update your fiddle, now works: http://jsfiddle.net/hQ5dZ/3/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were not closing the `div` elements, instead was creating new div child which was causing the `#fields` element to have only one child.

So `$('#fields').children().hide()` was hiding the child and then `$('#fields > :first-child').show()` was displaying it back.

```
<div id="fields">
    <div> <!-- fc-1 -->
        <input type="file" /> <!-- fc-2 -->
        <input type="button" value="+add" />
    </div> <!--not closed-->
    <div>
        <input type="file" /> <!-- fc-3 -->
        <input type="button" value="+add" />
    </div>
</div> <!--not closed-->

$('#fields').children().hide();
$('#fields > :first-child').show();
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/PDFcA/)

Also the second selector is updated because `#fields :first-child` will select all descendant elements of `#fields` which are the first child of its parent, in the above markup it will select all fields marked as `fc-x`

Comment: I gave you +1 because you fixed the selector by adding `>`, but you may like to add an explanation about that. (I know it works without it, but in my opinion it is more correct with it.)

Answer (score 7):

Your markup is invalid — you are not closing the `<div>` and `<input>` tags:

```
<div id="fields">    
    <div>
        <input type="file" />
        <input type="button" value="+add" />
    </div>
    <div> 
        <input type="file" />
        <input type="button" value="+add" />
    </div>
</div>
```

After changing the markup to a valid syntax, it's working - http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/nBbxY/

Answer (score 3):

Besides closing the needed tags you can shorten you jQuery code like so, for example:

```
$('#fields').children().hide().eq(0).show();
```

Working example online: http://jsfiddle.net/nBbxY/1/